# Escape sequences in vim (neovim) Python feedkeys

Tags: python, vim, neovim

I want to be able to control vim/neovim on a per-key basis with python scripting.  There is a function called feedkeys in the python vim module (vim.feedkeys) that is nearly what I want.  However, I haven't been able to figure out how to send things like function keys, arrow keys, pgup, pgdown etc as it always takes my strings completely literally.

As per the documentation for vim's feedkeys (vimscript version, not python)

> `feedkeys("\<CR>") simulates pressing of the <Enter> key. But feedkeys('\<CR>') pushes 5 characters.`

Things I've tried with the python counterpart that haven't worked (note, `<CR>` is just an example; I know I can use \n for that.  Nonetheless, this should simulate an enter keypress):

```
vim.feedkeys("\<CR>")
vim.feedkeys("<CR>")
vim.feedkeys("\<CR\>")
vim.call("feedkeys", "\<CR>")
vim.call("feedkeys", '"\<CR>"')
```

All of these were interpreted literally.  I want to do something like
`vim.feedkeys("\<F5>")`  etc.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't ideal, but it solves my issue well enough:

```
vim.command('call feedkeys("\<F5>")')
```

In case this is useful to anyone, I've written a general function that will handle the `\<>` escapes as well as double-quotes:

```
def fkeys(text): 
    firstsub = True
    for sub in text.split('"'):
        if firstsub:
            firstsub = False
        else:   
            vim.feedkeys('"')
        vim.command(f'call feedkeys("{sub}")')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being Captain Obvious, but it doesn't work, because Python is not VimScript.

See `:h nvim_replace_termcodes()` and `:h nvim_feedkeys()` for a complete example. In case of `<CR>`, simply byte value of 13 will do.

Comment: Yes, that is true of course.  I was just hoping that there was some escape sequence that would be interpreted by vim.feedkeys as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, because the interpretation of something like `"\<CR>"` is a function of VimL string literals. In other words, `feedkeys("\<CR>")` is the same thing as (probably) `feedkeys("\x0d")` — the function doesn't see the difference, the interpretation happens at a source code level. Naturally, Python doesn't have the same feature in the same way.

If you don't want to figure out what the escape sequence is for F5 and code it into your Python script, perhaps you could use `vim.eval()` to eval a VimL expression, e.g. `vim.eval(r'feedkeys("\<F5>")')`.